# How to remove the “ .0” in Decimal format and convert 1.01 to 1 in java

Tags: java, double

My application deals with prices, I am facing a small problem here. I will explain it clearly in steps.

Following are my inputs and OutPut should be.

> input  1.01  =  output 1
>
> input 1.748  = output 1.75
>
> input 1.98  =output 2
>
> input 1.49 = output 1.5
>
> input 20.0 = output 2

0

I have used the following code but I can't achieve it

```
    double calc = 1.98;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  
            calc = Double.valueOf(df.format(calc));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(calc).replaceAll("([0-9])\\.0+([^0-9]|$)", "$1$2"));

::> output is 1.98 which should be 2

double calc = 20.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");  
        calc = Double.valueOf(df.format(calc));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(calc).replaceAll("([0-9])\\.0+([^0-9]|$)", "$1$2"));

 ::> output is 20 this is correct for me.

double calc = 2.01;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  
        calc = Double.valueOf(df.format(calc));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(calc).replaceAll("([0-9])\\.0+([^0-9]|$)", "$1$2"));

::> output is 2.01  Which should be 2.
```

following code which I have tried.

Comment: Can't you just round it?

Comment: So round to the nearest 0.25?

Comment: So, you want a precision of 2  decimals when the actual number has 3, and a precision of 1 decimal when the actual number has 2? Quite a strange requirement.

Comment: @twntee Basically a pointless comment.

Comment: @EJP hmm, yes I tried giving him bit of idea I had, i wonder anyone will write code :/

Answer (score 0):

> input 1.01 = output 1

That implies using zero or one decimal places.

> input 1.748 = output 1.75

That implies adding .05 or possibly .005 and then using two decimal places.

> input 1.98 = output 2

This output could be described by either of the rules above.

> input 1.49 = output 1.5

That implies adding .05 or possibly .005 and then using one decimal place.

> input 20.0 = output 20

That implies using zero or one decimal places.

Your examples therefore aren't all instances of the same consistent rule. The only sense I can make of it is that you are only interested in a granularity of 0.25, but that's just my guess. You need to refine your requirement before you can possibly implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope it handles all your requirements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 20.0;
    int decimalPlaces = getDecimalPlaces(d) - 1;
    double res = Math.round(d * Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces))/Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces); // Rounding
    String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(res));
    int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
    if (getDecimalPlaces(res) == 1 && text.charAt(integerPlaces + 1) == '0') 
        System.out.println((int)res);
    else
        System.out.println(res);
}

private static int getDecimalPlaces(double d) {
    String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(d));
    int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
    int decimalPlaces = text.length() - integerPlaces - 1; // To Round
    return decimalPlaces;
}
```

Comment: 321.5455544546546 value is not coming properly can u please check it, and my out put is 321.545554454655.

Comment: What is your expected output in that example?

Comment: This code doesn't handle it. Why didn't you mention it in your post?

Comment: i have missed it out, while i am integrated code i have found this issue.